# JQuery html5 Loader not working in internet explorer

Tags: jpreloader

> I created a site with a background video...
> So to avoid page lagging i used a preloader.Works fine on every browser except ie.Can anyone help me this is a link to my site:**[Link](http://alex.elementfx.com)**
>
> 1. My site [Files](http://mediafire.com/download/b6fvbj5mw76ymhi/site.zip)

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work, I've the same problem.
Output *$("body").jpreLoader();* if browser != Chrome